# Change Toolbar Color for Xamarin Mobile App

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2019

I am new to xamarin.forms development and I am using VisualStudio 2019 to achieve the same. I am developing a sample shell application but unable to change the colour of toolbar(blue color in the picture). Could anyone please help me on this issue.

[image]

Comment: Did you try this property BarBackgroundColor in your Navigation

Comment: @Prasanth I didn't find a property like this in shellItem. Could you help me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We could set the background color by add `BackgroundColor="Green"` in the `shell.xaml`

For example we set it it `Green`

```
<Shell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
   xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
   xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
   mc:Ignorable="d"
   xmlns:local="clr-namespace:xxx"
   Title="xxx"
   BackgroundColor="Green"
   x:Class="xxx.AppShell">
```

This will let color of `TabBar` been changed to green at the same time . So we should create styles for `TabBar`.

```
<Shell.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Color x:Key="NavigationPrimary">#2196F3</Color> //color of TabBar

        <Style x:Key="BaseStyle" TargetType="Element">
            <Setter Property="Shell.BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource NavigationPrimary}" />
            <Setter Property="Shell.ForegroundColor" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="Shell.TitleColor" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="Shell.DisabledColor" Value="#B4FFFFFF" />
            <Setter Property="Shell.UnselectedColor" Value="#95FFFFFF" />
            <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarBackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource NavigationPrimary}" />
            <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarForegroundColor" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarUnselectedColor" Value="#95FFFFFF"/>
            <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarTitleColor" Value="White"/>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="MyBaseStyle" TargetType="Element">

            <Setter Property="Shell.ForegroundColor" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="Shell.TitleColor" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="Shell.DisabledColor" Value="#B4FFFFFF" />
            <Setter Property="Shell.UnselectedColor" Value="#95FFFFFF" />
            <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarBackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource NavigationPrimary}" />
            <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarForegroundColor" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarUnselectedColor" Value="#95FFFFFF"/>
            <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarTitleColor" Value="White"/>
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="ShellItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" />
        <Style TargetType="TabBar" BasedOn="{StaticResource MyBaseStyle}" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Shell.Resources>

<!-- Your Pages -->
<TabBar  >
    <Tab Title="xxx" Icon="xxx" >
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate xxx}" />
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="xxx" Icon="xxx">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate xxx}" />
    </Tab>
</TabBar>
```