# How Change toolbar color?(xamarin.forms)

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

How Change  toolbar color?(xamarin.forms)
how change blue to green ?

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
        xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:News.Pages"
         x:Class="News.MainPage"
        BarBackgroundColor="Green">
<TabbedPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem x:Name="btnSetting" Text="Setting" IconImageSource="Setting.png" Clicked="btnSetting_Clicked"/>
</TabbedPage.ToolbarItems>
<TabbedPage.Children>
    <pages:WorldPage Title="World" IconImageSource="world.png"/>
    <pages:TeredingPage Title="Trending" IconImageSource="trending.png"/>
    <pages:GamePage Title="Game" IconImageSource="xbox.png"/>
</TabbedPage.Children>
</TabbedPage>
```

[screen of app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAHqR.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change Toolbar Color for Xamarin Mobile App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58058913/change-toolbar-color-for-xamarin-mobile-app)

Answer (score 0):

In Android Resource/Layout/Toolbar xaml, there is one property

```
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
```

Changing background property like following code:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#ff99cc00"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" 
android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

[image]